# Newtonsoft Json.net error parsing boolean value

Tags: javascript, c#, json.net

I have some Json which seems perfectly valid when ran in JavaScript but fails when I try to parse it using Newtonsoft.parse in c#. I get the error parsing boolean value. I'm guessing newtonsoft doesn't like none string values which aren't integers or booleans.

in JavaScript:

```
var formDef = { "control" : formDef["c1"],  "c1" : "Button" }
```

in c#:

```
JObject.Parse("{\"control\":formDef[\"c1\"],\"c1\":\"Button\"}")
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd say similar, not dupicate, the linked question presents a serialization problem in addition of the deserialization one

Answer (score 3):

`formDef["c1"]` is valid Javascript, not valid JSON. Try running your JSON [through a linter](http://jsonlint.com/) to know if it's valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a .net JSON parser that would ignore that part but still give me access to the c1 key?

Comment: @SaipH- No because any JSON parser will only handle valid JSON. Instead, fix your JSON before trying to serialize/deserialize it.